# Example/documentation of Reference Input (CIP31) and Inline Datum (CIP32) with Emulator?

Tags: plutus, inline-datum

I am finding an example implementation of Reference Input (CIP31) and Inline Datum (CIP32) and want to test it with the `Plutus.Trace.Emulator`. I see some answers [like here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/9209/inlinedatum-on-referenceoutput-in-offchain-code) talking about `mustReferenceOutput` and `mustPayWithInlineDatumToPubKey`. Not sure if they are them. [playground.plutus.iohkdev.io](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/index.html) is my main go-to for plutus documentation. But both are not shown in it. An example cabal project would be very helpful.

Is there one out there?

Comment: You can run an updated version of the Haddock documentation via the plutus-apps repo. Git clone this repo and checkout v1.0.0. Enter a nix-shell in the repo and perform `build-and-serve-docs`. The hosted version you refer to is outdated. The functions that you want are defined in the `Ledger.Constraints` module.

Comment: I've been assuming the hosted version is updated or at least fairly so. This helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Fermat BTW, is there a way to get to the documentation without entering a nix-shell and compile the whole thing?

Comment: @Adam There's a new hosted alternative coming very soon, should be a few weeks max. Look out for PR in `plutus` and `plutus-apps` repos for hosted Haddock docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plutus Playground is no longer maintained and that instance will soon be taken down in favour of using the Trace Emulator.

Take a look at some of the plutus-contract integration tests for examples of using each of these constraints with the Trace Emulator. https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-contract/test/Spec/Contract/Tx/Constraints.

Note that `mustPayWithInlineDatumToPubKey` is deprecated in favour of `mustPayToPubKeyWithInlineDatum`

Comment: This is one hell of examples I didn't know existed. Right there in the git. Thanks.